# Dompdf show warning of Deprecation

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

Does anyone know why Chrome show this warning in PDF (generate with DOMPDF), but not in other pdf file like http://pepa.holla.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Reactjs_Succinctly.pdf?

> [Deprecation] Styling master document from stylesheets defined in HTML
>   Imports is deprecated, and is planned to be removed in M65, around
>   March 2018. Please refer to https://github.com/TakayoshiKochi/deprecate-style-in-html-imports for possible
>   migration paths.

[image: DOMPDF DEMO]

Comment: Looks like it's just saying you won't be able to use link tags to pull in external CSS. So, just put it all in a style tag. No bigee. Also, check out https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf . DOMPDF is not good.

Comment: Are you using [dompdf/dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) or [barryvdh/laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)?